# 이 문은 잘 안 닫혀요: is this sentence natural?

Tags: grammar, spoken-korean

Is the sentence below natural to native speaker?
I am confused because it is somewhat strange as 잘 and 안 are used together in the same sentence.

이 문은 잘 안 닫혀요.
Translation:This door does not close well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The expression of this type is commonly used.

> 잘 skillfully

나는 물건을 잘 잃어 버린다. I lost my things well(=frequently)

> That is, 잘 decorates the verb. Here 잘 gives an extended meaning of
>   the verb or comparative meaning.

1) 이 문은 잘 닫혀요. This door is locked well (Performance of this
door is better that that of other kinds of doors)

2) 이 문은 잘 안 닫히네요. This door is not locked well (Even though
this door is locked, it has low capacity when we compare it to other
standard.)

3) When we check all doors in the building, we can use 이 문은 잘
닫히네요. 저 문은 잘 안 닫혀요.

**[Add]**

(1) 저는 공부를 했어요.

저는 공부를 안 했어요.

저는 공부를 빨리 안 했어요 (A). I did not study quickly.

This has the same form by comparing it to the sentence 이 문은 잘 안
닫혀요.

In further, two sentences 저는 빨리 공부를 안 했어요 (B). 이 문은 잘
닫히지 않아요 share same form.

In the link, (A) and (B) are "a little awkward in Korean", because
there is a **more natural alternative** 저는 공부를 천천히 했어요.

(2) As far as I know, sentence containing 잘 may have alternative but we may use the both.

example : 칼이 잘 안들어요 (alternative : 칼이 무뎌요). This knife is not sharp well.

(3) Even though the form 빨리 + 안 is not used with 공부하다, it can be
used :

빨리 안 갈래 ? Go fast.

일이 빨리 안 되고 있다. The work is done slowly.

Comment: Thanks. Is this sentence natural 저는 빨리 안 공부했어요? In the page below the author said that  it sounds very awkward in Korean.  The reason is probably due to the fact that there are two adverbs being used. In this sentence, both “빨리” and “안” act as adverbs that indicate the degree to which the studying was done.
https://www.howtostudykorean.com/unit1/unit-1-lessons-1-8/unit-1-lesson-8/